# Changes in server view is not working in Grails

Tags: grails, gsp

I am working with Grails 2.4.2 and Tomcat 7 in Debian server.

Suppose I need to change a label of a field. If I change the label in server's view directory it is not working.

All I have to do is creating war again and deploy. But so far as I know, if any changes made in views no need to create war and deploy again.

Comment: changing "code" in the extracted war file of the app server is a predictability nightmare.

Comment: I found a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760735/modifying-groovy-code-at-runtime-in-grails-application

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the best way to deal with any dynamic content is to externalize it. Save the dynamic content into an external file where you can modify it. Grails' reloadable configuration could be of a great help. See http://www.tothenew.com/blog/externalize-and-reload-grails-configuration-dynamically/ to get an idea how this could be done.